# A-Frame scene optimization for mobile devices

Tags: aframe

I have created a grocery store project built on A-Frame with 63 products and 3 shelves.

- Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1x5u.jpg

On the laptop, after the grocery store is loaded, it holds 60 fps.

But it won't load on mobile devices - it's just crash the browser (tried on iPhone 13, Safari/Chrome and Samsung Galaxy S10, Chrome).

What guidelines should I follow to optimize the A-Frame scene for mobile devices?

Comment: Check if there is improvement if you leave 1 box of each type and 1 shelf. Because it looks like you could use [mesh instancing](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh) - could reduce draw calls from 185 to ~10

Comment: you could also try baking your textures in one single texture for each box you have. Other type of optimization in model such as decimating the model and compressing image can be tried. So that it supports in mobile

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski Thank you so much! Mesh instancing helped me: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-instanced-mesh?activeTab=readme

Comment: @AndreyMelnikov cool, I've made an answer out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the [Best Practices - Performance](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/best-practices.html#performance) docs.

In my experience the most common culprit is making too many draw calls. If you have identical objects it would be best to use [Instanced Meshes](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh).

Diarmid McKenzie made a cool [component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-instanced-mesh?activeTab=readme) if you don't want to dive into the `THREE.js` API

---

Use the [stats](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/stats.html#sidebar) component as often as possible, to keep track of the complexity of the scene (draw calls, geometries, lights).